# Tools to automate recording streaming radio

Tags: automation, streaming, audio-recording

Are there any tools that can automate recording online streaming radio? I've been using Total Recorder which has the following useful features:

1. Handy scheduler
2. Supports creating recording templates, so I can customize some high/low quality recording

Unfortunately it requires opening the streaming radio in a browser and can't have another sound source at the same time; it's recording what comes out from the speaker.

What I am looking for is given an online radio URL, the tool should be able to record the audio stream, no matter if I am playing any other music or not.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

schedule a vlc session, I've done this in the past and supports the different quality levels that your looking for.

http://videolan.org

Comment: This would be done in Tools > VLM Configuration if I recall correctly.

Comment: its been long enough ago that I can remember if its vlm or vlc with parameters  is a command line option that will do all the work!

Comment: Seems like finding the real streaming url is the hardest part. I am now having problem with opening the rstp or mms stream with vlc. Can't find the reason. Log at here (http://www.filefront.com/16510291/vlc-log.txt). Can anyone see what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both `mpg321` and `ogg123` can record streams directly to file, but you'll need to put your own scheduling mechanism in place.

Answer (score 1):

Install streamripper.   `$ apt-cache show streamripper`

> "This command-line tool can be used to record MPEG III  and OGG online
>   radio-streams into track-separated audio  files."

Can also be used as a relay server, so others on
 your network can listen while you record.

Answer (score 1):

StationRipper does the job pretty well.

http://www.stationripper.com/

Comment: You should explain why you think that it does the job pretty well, which features are present etc. Just dropping a link without further explanation isn't really helpful.

Comment: Record Shoutcast Audio and Video streams, iTunes Radio, Podcasts, Pandora.com, and Last.fm.
Auto-download Album art.
Ignore songs under a certain size.

It's been a while since I last used it, but as far as I can tell, Station Ripper is quite accurate in determining the gaps between songs and thus the start stop positions for song recordings.

Answer (score 0):

***What I am looking for is given a online radio url, and the tool can record the audio stream. No matter if I am playing any other music or not.***

[Screamer Radio](http://www.screamer-radio.com/) - it has to be running, but you can minimize it to a tray. Has a plethora of predefined stations already, and for recording you simply press the button. Beautiful thing really, simple yet functional.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[StreamWriter](https://streamwriter.org/en/) can do that. It can also record multiple streams at the same time and save tracks with tag names (title, artist etc). This feature needs to be enabled. Some details on that at the end of this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/666816/47206).

[image]